# CSS responsive Button position

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[image: Picture of how the button is positioned right now]

Right now I am trying to make my modal responsive but the "SAVE" button is not positioning as i want it to.
I want to have the button at the same position all the time, but right now it is disappearing.
My HTML and css looks as the following

```css
.delete{
    font-size: 16px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 60vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.delete .text-div{
    padding: 3px;
}
.delete .button-div{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    /* right: 50%;*/
    left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="delete">
    <div class="dialog-content-wrapper">
        <mat-toolbar matDialogTitle class="mat-accent m-0">
            <mat-toolbar-row fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                <span class="title dialog-title">Delete Entry</span>
                <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClose()" aria-label="Close dialog">
                    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </mat-toolbar-row>
        </mat-toolbar>
    </div>
    <div class="text-div">
        <span>Are you sure you want to delete this vacation entry?</span>
    </div>
    <div class="button-div">
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="button" (click)="buttonClick();onClose()">SAVE</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using a framework you should add it because now, it is quite broken compared to your image. Or you have missing CSS

Comment: Right, im using angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't need to wrap single elements into divs, it's not a very good practice regarding accessibility.

Regarding your question, where exactly do you want your button to be? If its position is set to `relative`, it will be positioned *relative to the nearest positioned ancestor*. That means that you need to put a `position` property to the `.delete` div (usually, `relative` will suffice).

Another way to achieve what you want (if I understand it correctly) would be adding `align-self: end` to the button element, since it's wrapped inside a flex container.

Comment: That's the right answer. Also nice to mention, that he's positioning .button-div 80% from left, so if SAVE button is wider than 20% of the available space, it will be simply cut off. (like on the screen)

Comment: Yes. It would be nicer with a `right: 0`, although I'm not a fan of positioning elements like this. Flex is much better.

Comment: The align-self method worked for me! Thanks!